# Check some property for every line of a file

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have several (427 to be precise) text files with a million lines each containing 31 numbers separated be spaces (possible double spaces). However there might be some data corruption and there may be lines containing junk.

I now want to check if every line satisfies the property of containing 31 items separated by spaces (I assume that those items are numbers. A method which checks that too would be better).

My current way is

```
while read line;
do
   if [ $(echo "$line" | sed 's/ /\n/g' | grep -v "^$" | wc -l) -ne 31 ]
   then
      echo "$file bad";
   fi
done < $file
```

This replaces all spaces of a line by newlines, filters empty lines, counts the number of lines and compares it to 31.

This approach is slow and there's probably a much better way involving some fancy regular expression. What would be a faster way?

Comment: You're gonna wait forever while million string file will be checked line by line within pure bash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do:

```
awk 'NF != 31 || /[^0-9 -]/ {print FILENAME ":" FNR ": " $0}' file1 file2...
```

To report the lines that don't have 31 fields or have non-digits. Not as strict as @manatwork's solution as it wouldn't bark on `---` or `9-8` for instance, but it might be more efficient.

Comment: As your regular expression checks the entire `$0`, better allow spaces too.

Comment: Oops, good point @manatwork. Edited now.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just `grep` alone?

```
bash-4.2$ cat file
1 2 -3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
32 33 -34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 L 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
63 64 -65 66 67 68 69
70 71 -72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

# listing bad lines in the file
bash-4.2$ grep -Exv '(-?[[:digit:]]+ +){30}-?[[:digit:]]+' file
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 L 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
63 64 65 66 67 68 69

# listing files with bad lines
bash-4.2$ grep -Exvl '(-?[[:digit:]]+ +){30}-?[[:digit:]]+' -- *
file
```

Comment: is it possible to extend that to negative numbers as well?

Comment: @stefan, updated to allow negative numbers too.

Comment: @rush, I was thinking about that, but was not sure whether to handle it or not. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: can you please explain why you separated one number?

Comment: You may need to allow leading and trailing spaces as well.

Comment: @stefan, because otherwise the expression would require trailing spaces after the 31th number. If optional leading and trailing spaces are allowed in the lines, better go with [Stephane Chazelas's `awk` solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/70342).

Answer (score 1):

You can read the line into an array using `read -a`, and then check the size of the array. This should be considerably better than spawning a subshell to fork 3 processes each line.

```
while read -ra line;
do
    if (( ${#line[@]} != 31 )); then
        echo "$file bad"
    fi
done < "$file"
```